# how to embed mp3 file in web page

Tags: javascript, web-applications

I have set of mp3 files that when page is requested need to randomly pick up one file and should play as background music in my web page is there a cross browser way(need to work major web browsers such as IE,firefox,chrome) of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use JW Player http://www.longtailvideo.com/players/jw-flv-player/ to play MP3, but please don't play music without the user request. This will make the user to GTFO of your website.

Example: http://www.longtailvideo.com/support/jw-player-setup-wizard?example=202

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='swfobject.js'></script>

<div id='mediaspace'>This text will be replaced</div>

<script type='text/javascript'>
  var so = new SWFObject('player.swf','mpl','470','24','9');
  so.addParam('allowfullscreen','true');
  so.addParam('allowscriptaccess','always');
  so.addParam('wmode','opaque');
  so.addVariable('duration','33');
  so.addVariable('file','http://www.longtailvideo.com/jw/upload/bunny.mp3');
  so.write('mediaspace');
</script>
```

Comment: thanks lves , but this player use html 5 markup so this might cause issues to older browsers or browsers that do not have html 5 implementations still.

Comment: The HTML 5 markup is optional. You should just use the flash embed code. Check this out:http://www.longtailvideo.com/support/jw-player-setup-wizard?example=202. I pasted the example in the response box above