# HTML How to add Background Music

Tags: html

How do I add Background Music such as Youtube video to Music.  I don't want to add my songs from the harddrive, just online song to background.

This way If people come to my website there is some kind of music to listen too.

Thanks and if you know the code please tell me and thank you for your time.

I think there is something to do with Iframe

Comment: use flash or html5's audio tag.

Comment: Please, please, don't do that!

Comment: Is it bad not to have background music

Comment: The overwhelming consensus on SO is that it's bad to *have* background music. However, here is one example for how to do it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4343060/how-to-embed-mp3-file-in-web-page

Comment: @Nikhil: If you must do it anyway, please make it optional and non-default, i.e. have a button to turn it on.

Comment: Also in addition to playing background music can you also maximize my browser for me? I like that.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Show your work. Please don't ask people to write code for you; SO isn't an advice forum or a code writing service.

Answer (score 4):

If your background music music is from YouTube, the way I do it is to make the size 1px by 1px so you can't see it then add a loop and autoplay to it.

```
<iframe width="1" height="1" wmode="transparent" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/VIDEO_ID?autoplay=1&loop=1&playlist=VIDEO_ID" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen>
```

The VIDEO_ID is are the letters, numbers and symbols after the www.youtube.com/watch?v= (VIDEO_ID)

Answer (score 1):

You can use html tag `audio` and `autoplay` attribute

```
<audio type="audio/mp3" src="<url for song>" autoplay loop>
```

Answer (score 0):

Youtube has a feature called embed, it's located below every video on the website. Take the code given and insert the markup into your HTML document and viola!

Some videos may having embedding blocked so just find another one.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but this embed feature will it embed videos not music.  I want to extract the music from the videos that is shown in youtube, so this way it plays music.

Answer (score 0):

This should work in the head html:

```
<audio autoplay loop "{Replace this text in theese brackets with this music file including the path}" type="audio/fileextension"/>
```